# Add an element in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am looking for a way to insert items inside elements in angular js.

Ill try to show how it is.

```
<item1> </item1>
```

insert an item like this

```
<item1>
    <item2> </item2>
</item1>
```

It also should insert all the data you require (it means it must execute the template of item2 when initialize).

I want to insert items **dynamically**, while press a button a new element is inserted into item1. The new one will be of a different type type2 and should inherit all the propertys and attributes of it's kind (item3, item3.. and so on).

Comment: create a directive `item1` which template is `<item2></item2>`

Comment: Angular would be extreme overkill for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

```
<item data-ng-include="'partials/your-template.html'"></item>
```

And attach to his own controller if needed.

```
<item ng-controller="YourCtrl" data-ng-include="'partials/your-template.html'"></item>
```

You can also create a custom directive like floribon advice, use ng-repeat, ng-bind-html...

**Update from your comment**

Use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) in this case

```
<item ng-show="isClicked">{{data}}</item>
<button ng-click="isClicked = true">insert</button>
```

That's the basics of angular use, you must read the [bible](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) before become a priest.

Comment: but the idea is to update, insert dynamically while you press a button, I have changed the description in order to explain it better, thanks anyway